# Getting Value of Drop-Down List with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wanting to make a drop-down menu for a website, and then obtain the value of the user's decision with JavaScript. I have followed other resources on the web; but it doesn't seem to work. It just keeps returning the word 'Select something...'; even when I change it.

```
     <select id="dropDown" onChange="output()">

            <option value="0">Select something...</option>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>

        </select>

        <script>
         var value = document.getElementById("dropDown");
         var strUsr = value.options[value.selectedIndex].text;

         function output(){
               console.log(value);
        }

        output();
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the value of the option selected or the text ? :P

Comment: Oh sorry, I am wanting the text associated with each field.

Answer (score 2):

It will working for you

```
<select id="dropDown" onchange="output(this)">

        <option value="0">Select something...</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

function output(dropDown)
{
    alert(dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<select id="dropDown" onChange="output(this)"> //added this here
    <option value="0">Select something...</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

function output(sender){
               alert(sender.options[sender.selectedIndex].text);
        }
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/9MNfA/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a select element that looks like this:

```
<select id="dd">
<option value="1">t1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">t2</option>
<option value="3">t3</option>
</select>
```

Running this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("dd");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

strUser will be 2.

```
var e = document.getElementById("dd");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

strUser will be t2